# Syntax differences in variadic template parameter pack forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

While working with variadic templates I have come across two different ways of writing a call to `std::forward`, but I am left wondering what the actual difference between the two syntaxes?

```
template<typename... T>
void one(T&&... args)
{
    foo(std::forward<T&&...>(args...));
}
template<typename... T>
void two(T&&... args)
{
    foo(std::forward<T&&>(args)...);
}
```

According to my compilers these are both valid syntax, and in most cases the compiler does not complain. But I have found some cases where one or the other is correct but the compiler does not say why in detail.

Is one more correct that the other?
Do they serve different purposes?

Comment: The first one is wrong and does not actually compile except for one-element packs.

Comment: It's called pack expansion as it is exactly that. Calling the first example with `one(2, 2.3, 2.3f);` would make the function body `foo(std::forward<int&&, double&&, float&&>(2, 2.3, 2.3f)` which wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `...` placement tells the compiler where to expand the pack, once for each element in the thing before it (hard to phrase easily but I'll illustrate below).

Let's consider a pack `T = {int, double, char}` and `args = {1, 2.0, '3'}`

Your first example (`one`) will expand `T` inside of the `<>` and then `args` inside of the `()` so it becomes

```
foo(std::forward<T&&...>(args...));  // becomes:
foo(std::forward<int&&, double&&, char&&>(1, 2.0, '3'));
```

This is not how `std::forward` works since it only expects one argument.  Your second example (`two`) says to expand the whole call to `std::forward` once for each item in the packs, so it becomes

```
foo(std::forward<T&&>(args)...);  // becomes:
foo(std::forward<int&&>(1), std::forward<double&&>(2.0),std::forward<char&&>('3'));
```

As for why these both compiled fine, the result is identical if you called with only one argument. If you never called it at all then it wouldn't be instantiated.