# Declaration type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'Args'

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm triying to code a listener/callback class, but I `get Declaration type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'Args'` in the call method.
I want to call as:
`listeners.call (&ListenerType::myCallbackMethod, arg1, arg2, etc);`

Ok, I can create many call methods with different number of args, but if can I do only one method is better

```
template <typename ...Args>
void call (void (ListenerClass::*callbackFunction) (Args), Args && ...value) // Compiler error: Declaration type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'Args'
{
    auto iter = listeners.begin(); 
    while (iter != listeners.end())
    {
        if(auto p = iter->lock())
        {
            (p->*callbackFunction) (std::forward<Args>(value)...); 
            ++iter;
        }
        else
            iter = listeners.erase(iter);
    }
};
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: It's all in the error message. Where do you have a declaration with an unexpanded parameter pack named `Args`? Expand it.

Comment: Tried to reformat to avoid horizontal scroll bars, but changed the name of the argument - which invalidates the correct answer.  I've rolled back.

Comment: As an aside, your design is a horribly bad idea.  Forwarding references don't work that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the issue is here:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void call (void (ListenerClass::*callbackFunction) /*here->*/(Args), Args && ...value)
```

This should be:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void call (void (ListenerClass::*callbackFunction) (Args...), Args && ...value)
```

You are specifying that the function pointer you are passing with take parameters of type `Args` which is a parameter pack. So You just need to expand that parameter pack with `...`

Comment: Surely `Args` must be expanded in the call to `std::forward` too in that case?

Comment: `std::forward<Args>(value)...` It is already expanded, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41071580/1865694 http://stackoverflow.com/q/41071181/1865694

Comment: I think you now have another problem. Args can be deduced two different ways.

Comment: But wouldn't deduction fail if Args was deduced as two different things? I suppose the question is... which occurrence of args will the compiler try to deduce Args from?